# How to update webpage in real-time without refresh from Firebase?

Tags: firebase, web-applications, firebase-realtime-database

This is web app html code that uses firebase. The goal is retrieve qty in a real time without refresh/reload the page.

How can it be done? Thxs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head><meta charset="utf-8"></head>
<body>
    <span class="qty" id="qty">0</span>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.3.1/firebase.js"></script>
    <script>
        var config = { ... };
        firebase.initializeApp(config);
    </script>
    <script>
        var dbRef = firebase.database().ref();
        var startListening = function() {
            dbRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
                var warehouse = snapshot.child("prod_id/stats").val();
                document.getElementById("qty").innerHTML = warehouse.qty
            });
        }
        startListening();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since firebase uses unique id data, when you reference something like `warehouse.qty`, And using `child_added` instead of `value`, You'll probably will end up with `null` data because the path is not correct.

First check where is your data stored. Check the path. is it in `prod_id/stats/qty`? or `prod_id/stats/<some-unique-key>/qty`?.

If it is in `prod_id/stats/qty` , You'll probably want to change the the `child_added` to `value` . As in code below :

```
var dbRef = firebase.database().ref();
var startListening = function() {
     dbRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
        var warehouse = snapshot.child("prod_id/stats").val();
        document.getElementById("qty").innerHTML = warehouse.qty
      });
 }
startListening();
```

Comment: The path is "prod_id/stats/qty". Works fine.

Comment: Glad it help you.